# How do I target a particular element from group of elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

```
<a class="group">
    <span class="letter">A</span>
    <span class="letter">B</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
    <span class="letter">D</span>
</a>
```

Hello,
I want to target only the span that has the text C using javascript. I cannot use its position in the group because that changes dynamically.

Comment: Either add a class or `document.querySelectorAll('.letter').filter(span => span.textContent === "C")[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't rely on the position, you'll have to go searching for it by looking at its text, perhaps by using [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
const found = $(".group .letter").filter(
    (_, span) => span.textContent.trim() === "C"
);
```

```js
const found = $(".group .letter").filter((_, span) => span.textContent.trim() === "C");
found.addClass("highlight");
```

```css
.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="group">
    <span class="letter">A</span>
    <span class="letter">B</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
    <span class="letter">D</span>
</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or using the DOM directly instead of via a library, using `querySelectorAll`, spread that out into an array, and then using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const found = [...document.querySelectorAll(".group .letter")]
    .find((span) => span.textContent.trim() === "C");
```

```js
const found = [...document.querySelectorAll(".group .letter")].find((span) => span.textContent.trim() === "C");
found?.classList.add("highlight");
```

```css
.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="group">
    <span class="letter">A</span>
    <span class="letter">B</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
    <span class="letter">D</span>
</a>
```

Or alternatively with a loop (no intermediary array):

```
for (const span of document.querySelectorAll(".group .letter")) {
    if (span.textContent.trim() === "C") {
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

```js
for (const span of document.querySelectorAll(".group .letter")) {
    if (span.textContent.trim() === "C") {
        span.classList.add("highlight");
        break;
    }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="group">
    <span class="letter">A</span>
    <span class="letter">B</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
    <span class="letter">D</span>
</a>
```

---

One small note: The jQuery example will find **all** matching elements and return it as a jQuery object (a wrapper around the elements). The DOM examples only look for the **first** element. My impression was you had only one, so that would be appropriate, but if you want a DOM version that finds all of them, change `find` to `filter` in the first DOM example and then loop the resulting array.

```
const found = [...document.querySelectorAll(".group .letter")]
    .filter((span) => span.textContent.trim() === "C");
for (const span of found) {
    // ...
}
```

```js
const found = [...document.querySelectorAll(".group .letter")]
    .filter((span) => span.textContent.trim() === "C");
for (const span of found) {
    span.classList.add("highlight");
}
```

```css
.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="group">
    <span class="letter">A</span>
    <span class="letter">B</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
    <span class="letter">D</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
</a>
```

Or, again, a loop, just don't break out of it:

```
for (const span of document.querySelectorAll(".group .letter")) {
    if (span.textContent.trim() === "C") {
        span.classList.add("highlight");
        // No `break;` here
    }
}
```

```js
for (const span of document.querySelectorAll(".group .letter")) {
    if (span.textContent.trim() === "C") {
        span.classList.add("highlight");
        // No `break;` here
    }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="group">
    <span class="letter">A</span>
    <span class="letter">B</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
    <span class="letter">D</span>
    <span class="letter">C</span>
</a>
```